# Opening a file with universal newlines in binary mode in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

We're (finally) upgrading an application to Python 3.

One thing we have to upgrade is rewriting a CSV file using normal newlines.

The original (python 2) code looks like this:

```py
import csv

IN_PATH = 'in.csv'
OUT_PATH = 'out.csv'

# Opens the original file in 'text mode' (which has no effect on Python 2)
# and with 'universal newlines',
# meaning \r, \n, and \r\n all get treated as line separators.
with open(IN_PATH, 'rU') as in_csv:
    with open(OUT_PATH, 'w') as out_csv:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(in_csv)
        csv_writer = csv.writer(out_csv)

        for tupl in csv_reader:
            csv_writer.writerow(tupl)
```

These CSV files are user-provided. This means:

- we have no control over what newline characters they use, so we need to handle all of them.
- we don't know the encoding of the file at this stage in the process.

Because we don't know the encoding, we cannot decode the bytestrings into text.

To make this work on Python 3, first we changed it to use `io.open()`, which is mostly compatible with py3's `open()`. Now we can't use 'text mode' any more, because on Python 3 that requires decoding the bytestrings, and we don't know the encoding.

However, using 'binary mode' means we can no longer use universal-newlines, since that's only available in text mode.

```py
# Opens the original file in 'binary mode'
# (because we don't know the encoding, so we can't decode it)
# FIXME: How to get universal newline support?
with io.open(IN_PATH, 'rb') as in_csv:
    with io.open(OUT_PATH, 'wb') as out_csv:
```

Note that, although the `U` mode character is no longer supported in python 3, it does use universal newlines by default *in text mode*. It doesn't appear to have any way of using universal newlines in binary mode.

How can we make this code work in Python 3?

Comment: Note that the csv module does its own newline handling (to properly manage embedded newlines). Have you tried just using a plain ``open`` and ``csv.reader``? https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3

Comment: plain open in python 3 is equivalent to `io.open` in python 2, so using `io.open` is the way to achieve compatibility with both - hence why I did that

Comment: Good point. Just to reiterate though, are you sure that the newline handling of csv is not sufficient?

Comment: Note that you *have* to open the file in text mode for Python3 - ``csv`` cannot handle bytes.

Comment: BTW, in Python 2, the `csv` module expects files to be opened in binary mode. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: Use ASCII with surrogate escapes on Python3:

```
def text_open(*args, **kwargs):
    return open(*args, encoding='ascii', errors='surrogateescape', **kwargs)
```

---

The [recommended approach](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#files-in-an-unknown-encoding) if you know only a partial encoding (e.g. ASCII `\r` and `\n`) is to use surrogate escapes for unknown code points:

> What can you do if you need to make a change to a file, but don’t know
>   the file’s encoding? If you know the encoding is ASCII-compatible and
>   only want to examine or modify the ASCII parts, you can open the file
>   with the surrogateescape error handler:

This uses reserved placeholders to embed the unknown bytes in your text stream. For example, the byte `b'\x99'` becomes the "unicode" code point `'\udc99'`. This works for both reading and writing, allowing you to preserve arbitrary embedded data.

The common line endings (`\n`, `\r`, `\r\n`) are all well-defined in ASCII. It is thus sufficient to use ASCII encoding with surrogate escapes.

For compatibility code, it is easiest to provide separate Python 2 and Python 3 versions of the divergent functionality. `open` is sufficiently similar that for most use cases, you just need to insert the surrogate escape handling.

```
if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    def text_open(*args, **kwargs):
        return open(*args, encoding='ascii', errors='surrogateescape', **kwargs)
else:
    text_open = open
```

This allows using universal newlines without knowing the exact encoding. You can use this to directly read or transcribe files:

```
with text_open(IN_PATH, 'rU') as in_csv:
    with text_open(OUT_PATH, 'wU') as out_csv:
        for line in in_csv:
            out_csv.write(line)
```

If you need further formatting of the `csv` module, the text stream provided by `text_open` is sufficient as well. To handle non-ascii delimiters/padding/quotes, translate them from a bytestring to the appropriate surrogate.

```
if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    def surrogate_escape(symbol):
        return symbol.decode(encoding='ascii', errors='surrogateescape')
else:
    surrogate_escape = lambda x: x

Dezimeter = surrogate_escape(b'\xA9\x87')
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the right answer, at least for py3-only code. It's a bit frustrating for supporting _both_ versions, since surrogateescape isn't available on py2. Looks like python-future has a surrogateescape backport but it looks hard to plug into io.open, meaning (as you pointed out) we need two completely separate code paths for py2 and py3. Thanks for the research you've put into this

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a built-in way to do what you want in Python 3.  Without knowing the encoding, you only know for sure that you have a bunch of bytes - you're not sure which ones of them mean the characters `\r` or `\n`.

Your Python 2 code was probably using the system default encoding according to `sys.getdefaultencoding()` to inform the built-in universal newline normalizer (don't quote me, I haven't looked at the implementation), and if your system is like mine, that was probably `ascii`.

Fortunately I think most encodings (including `utf-8`) only differ in the mappings of their higher-order characters (above the `ascii` range).  So, it's not a terrible assumption to make that the byte `10` means `\n` and `13` means `\r` for all common encodings - meaning you could just do the replacement yourself by reading the input byte-by-byte (or rather, using a sliding two-byte window).

Warning: I haven't exhaustively tested the following code for behavior around repeated sequences like `\r\r\r` or weird things like `\n\r`, so while it may handle those sanely it also may not.  Please do test on your own data.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import io
import six  # optional (but hugely helpful for a 2 to 3 port)


def normalize(prev, curr):
    ''' Given current and previous bytes, get tuple of bytes that should be written

    :param prev: The byte just before the read-head
    :type  prev: six.binary_type
    :param curr: The byte at the read-head
    :type  curr: six.binary_type
    :returns   : A tuple containing 0, 1, or 2 bytes that should be written
    :rtype     : Tuple[six.binary_type]
    '''
    R = six.binary_type(b'\r')
    N = six.binary_type(b'\n')
    if   curr == R:         # if we find R, can't dump N yet because it might be start of RN sequence and we must consume N too
        return ()
    elif curr == N:         # if we find N, doesn't matter what previous byte was - dump N
        return (N,)
    elif prev == R:         # we know current not N or R; if previous byte was R - dump N, then the current byte
        return (N, curr)
    else:                   # we know current not N or R and prev not R - dump the current byte
        return (curr,)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    IN_PATH = 'in.csv'
    OUT_PATH = 'out.csv'

    with io.open(IN_PATH, mode='rb') as in_csv:
        with io.open(OUT_PATH, mode='wb') as out_csv:
            prev = None                                 # at start, there is no previous byte
            curr = six.binary_type(in_csv.read(1))      # at start, the current byte is the input file's first byte
            while curr:                                 # loop over all bytes in the input file
                for byte in normalize(prev, curr):      # loop over all bytes returned from the normalizing function
                    print(repr(byte))                   # debugging
                    out_csv.write(byte)                 # write each byte to the output file
                prev = curr                             # update value of previous byte
                curr = six.binary_type(in_csv.read(1))  # update value of current byte
```

This works for me on both Python 2.7.16 and 3.7.3, using an input file I created (using Python 3) like this:

```
import io

with io.open('in.csv', mode='wb', encoding='latin-1') as fp:
    fp.write('à,b,c\n')
    fp.write('1,2,3\r')
    fp.write('4,5,6\r\n')
    fp.write('7,8,9\r')
    fp.write('10,11,12\n')
    fp.write('13,14,15')
```

It also works using `encoding='UTF-8'` (as it should).

It's not necessary to use `six.binary_type()` like I did, but I find it a helpful reminder of the semantics of the data I'm working with, esp when writing cross-version code.

I spent a while trying to figure out if there was a nicer way to do this than manually examining all the bytes, but was unsuccessful.  If anyone else finds a way, I'm interested in seeing it!

Comment: Thanks, this looks useful. I expect performance would be pretty shocking but maybe it'll be acceptable if we add buffered reads. I'll do some testing, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `open` function in Python 3 has an argument `newline`.  Setting it to `None` enables universal newline mode.

```
import csv

IN_PATH = 'in.csv'
OUT_PATH = 'out.csv'

with open(IN_PATH, 'r', newline=None) as in_csv:
    with open(OUT_PATH, 'w') as out_csv:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(in_csv)
        csv_writer = csv.writer(out_csv)

        for tupl in csv_reader:
            csv_writer.writerow(tupl)
```

Examples:

Example file:

```
a,b,c\n
1,2,3\r
4,5,6\r\n
7,8,9
```

Example code:

```
with open('file.csv', 'r', newline=None) as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    for line in reader:
        print(line)

# prints:
['a', 'b', 'c']
['1', '2', '3']
['4', '5', '6']
['7', '8', '9']
```

Comment: Well, I alluded to that in my question - `newline=None` is the default actually, but doesn't do anything in binary mode.